# Verificar URL con HttpServletRequest para evitar caracteres invalidos en los parametros que se envian

Tags: java, http, https, filtro

Estoy intentando aplicar un filter a mi aplicacion para que en la URL no vengan caracteres que no deseo y que mas adelante pueden afectar el funcionamiento de mi aplicacion
He intentado con varios metodos pero no he podido capturarla y modificarla

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

   HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
   if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
     String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();
     String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getQueryString();
   }
}
```

Estoy intentando con esto pero despues de varios intentos no logro capturar la URL

Con que funcion o de que manera podria capturarla y modificarla

Gracias

Comment: Agregaste en el filter al web.xml.?  Que es lo que intentar hacer cambiar el charset o que realmente?

Comment: Si el filter ya esta en el web.xml

Comment: la url que llega es algo como http://127.0.0.1:8080/valor='5' y quiero quitarle esas comillas sencillas y que queda http://127.0.0.1:8080/valor=5

Comment: ya entendi te voy a enviar un ejemplo Completo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejemplo del filtro:

```
  import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author Administrator
     */
    public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    
        private String encoding;
    
        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
            //VERIFICAR QUE EL REQUEST ENCODING ESTE PRESENTE PARA EVITAR PROBLENAS DE CHARSET.
            encoding = filterConfig.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
            if (encoding == null) {
                encoding = "UTF-8";
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            //APLICAMOS EL ENCODING CORRECTO.
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
            response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
            //DEVOLVEMOS EL REQUEST FILSTRADO: FilteredRequest Y response.
            chain.doFilter(new FilteredRequest(request), response);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void destroy() {
    
        }
    
        //CLASE PARA FILTRAR EL REQUEST.
        static class FilteredRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    
            //ACA PONEMOS LOS CARATERES INDESEADOS. EN TU CASO ES ' PERO PODES DEFINIR TU PROPIA REGLA.
            static String InvalidChars = "'";
    
            public FilteredRequest(ServletRequest request) {
                super((HttpServletRequest) request);
            }
    
            //ESTA FUNCION REMUEVE EN ESTE EJEMPLO TODOS LOS CHARS '
            public String sanitize(String input) {
                String result = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                    if (InvalidChars.indexOf(input.charAt(i)) == -1) {
                        result += input.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
           
            public String getParameter(String paramName) {
                String value = super.getParameter(paramName);
               //if ("myParam".equals(value)){} <- si ya sabes el nombre del parametro a filtrar pones una condicion para que no filtre todos los parametros.
                value = sanitize(value);
                return value;
            }
    
            public String[] getParameterValues(String paramName) {
                String values[] = super.getParameterValues(paramName);
                for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
//if ("myParam".equals(values[index])){} <- si ya sabes el nombre del parametro a filtrar pones una condicion para que no filtre todos los parametros.
                    values[index] = sanitize(values[index]);
                }
                return values;
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Cual es el string que le voy a enviar a las funciones ??

Comment: No entendi tu pregunta. Pero asi como esta el codigo elimina todas las comillas simples que recibis como valores de los parametros post o get. En la variable InvalidChars pones todos los caracteres que queres que elimine de los parametros. No tenes que enviar ningun string.